# expo init is throwing error regarding missing export main in is-promise

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I have installed expo globally using npm on windows 10.
while i am running the basic script - expo init app-name, i am receiving the following error :

```
Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\Vaibhav Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\is-promise'
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:499:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:854:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vaibhav Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
```

This is the is-promise file which the error refers :

```
module.exports = isPromise;
module.exports.default = isPromise;

function isPromise(obj) {
  return !!obj && (typeof obj === 'object' || typeof obj === 'function') && typeof obj.then === 'function';
}
```

I haven't modified it. 
I

Comment: your error seems different but it is in the same place so it might help... so I went to `..node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/is-promise/` and removed `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` file and it built a project. I hope you will figure out this error!

Answer (score 0):

install expo-cli with sudo 
"sudo npm install expo-cli --global"